# How can I place rotated text against a table with HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, transformation

I'm trying to put text on the left of a table. The text is rotated so that way it looks like it is resting on the left of the table. I have the css working correctly, but when trying to place it next to my table it breaks and the text flies across the page. I'm not sure how to achieve this. Currently I'm using this fiddle for testing though.

```
<body>
<label class="rotate"><small>Live Updating!</small></label>
<table>
    <tr id="teamnames">
        <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="teamscores">
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kingdamian42/b4EzJ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use the tag caption instead of label.

For your transformation you are missing transform-origin to help you.

For IE <9 you may use as well writing-mode.

Here is a test in a code editeur that works in real IE8 too.

http://liveweave.com/HYqDqn

```
caption {
  -webkit-transform:  rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin:top left;
  -moz-transform:  rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform-origin:top left;
  -o-transform:  rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform-origin:top left;
  -ms-transform:  rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform-origin:top left;
  transform:  rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin:top left;
}
```

CC for IE

```
   caption {
      writing-mode:tb-lr;
      margin-left:-1em;
      width:100%;
      white-space:nowrap;
      text-indent:2em;
    }
```

the full page to test

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Liveweave</title>    
    <!-- Place cursor after this and select a
JavaScript library from the menu above -->



  <!-- Supports context-sensitive CSS3 auto-completion -->
  <!-- Style starts here. Try adding new CSS tags. -->
  <style type="text/css">    


    table, td {
      border:solid;
      width:500px;
      height:200px;
      margin:auto;

    }
    caption {
      -webkit-transform:  rotate(90deg);
      -webkit-transform-origin:top left;
      -moz-transform:  rotate(90deg);
      -moz-transform-origin:top left;
      -o-transform:  rotate(90deg);
      -o-transform-origin:top left;
      -ms-transform:  rotate(90deg);
      -ms-transform-origin:top left;
      transform:  rotate(90deg);
      transform-origin:top left;

    }

  </style>
  <!--[if lte IE 9]>
  <style>
    caption {
      writing-mode:tb-lr;
      margin-left:-1em;
      width:100%;
      white-space:nowrap;
      text-indent:2em;
    }
  </style>
  <![endif]-->
  <!-- Style ends here -->

</head>  

<body>
<table>
  <caption class="rotate"><small>Live Updating!</small></caption>
    <tr id="teamnames">
        <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="teamscores">
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's close to what I'm looking for, but not as tidy as I'd like. I don't think what I'm looking for is easily possible.